# Best practices to add FluentFTP to IServiceCollection in .NET 6

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, fluentftp

I want to use FluentFTP in .NET6.
Is there best practice to add FluentFtp.FtpClient to IServiceCollection?
Is there any implementation like IHttpClientFactory & AddHttpClient?

I tried the following code. It works but not best.

Some my wrapper

```cs
public class MyFtpClient
{
   private readonly FluentFTP.FtpClient _client;

   public MyFtpClient(MyFtpClientSettings settings)
   {
       _client = new FtpClient(); // create instance with settings
   }
}
```

In Porgram.cs

```cs
services.AddScoped(x => new MyFtpClient(settings);
```

Comment: What does `It works but not best.` mean?

Comment: I guess it better to implement a factory for FtpClient like IHttpClientFactory. Using FtpClient directly may cause some sockets exhaustion.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests